# Quit threads if take longer than X seconds

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using Ruby threads like this:

```
threads = []

for page in pages
  threads << Thread.new(page) { |myPage|

    h = Net::HTTP.new(myPage, 80)
    puts "Fetching: #{myPage}"
    resp, data = h.get('/', nil )
    puts "Got #{myPage}:  #{resp.message}"
  }
end

threads.each { |aThread|  aThread.join }
```

Let's say I wanted to kill all threads that are still running after a minute. How would I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually timeout my operations with [Timeout](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/timeout/rdoc/index.html):

```
require "timeout"
Timeout.timeout(seconds) do
 ...
end
```

Maybe [this](http://www.docunext.com/blog/2009/08/simple-ruby-timeout-example.html) can help, so in your case, I think something like this should work:

```
begin
  Timeout.timeout(5) do
    for page in pages
      threads << Thread.new(page) { |myPage|

        h = Net::HTTP.new(myPage, 80)
        puts "Fetching: #{myPage}"
        resp, data = h.get('/', nil )
        puts "Got #{myPage}:  #{resp.message}"
      }
    end
    threads.each { |aThread|  aThread.join }
  end
rescue Timeout::Error
   # kill threads here
end
```

But are you sure your controller is the best place to be doing this? Wouldn't they be better off in a background task?

Comment: what would I wrap this around? I want to kill the threads but still render the page

Comment: And if the time limit expires, it's the equivalent of a kill?

Comment: I can't stress enough that if you've gone ahead and avoided using a background task in favour of using Threads inside a controller, you're making a big mistake.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of resorting to thread management, I would simply add this line after the construction of `h`:

```
...
h = Net::HTTP.new(myPage, 80)
h.read_timeout = 60
...
```

That way, the HTTP request will timeout after 60 secs and the thread will exit gracefully.

**EDIT**: Of course, you have to check if the request was successful or did timeout. ;)

**FURTHER EDIT**: Let me expand your code:

```
threads = []

for page in pages
  threads << Thread.new(page) { |myPage|
    begin
      h = Net::HTTP.new(myPage, 80)
      h.read_timeout = 60
      puts "Fetching: #{myPage}"
      resp, data = h.get('/', nil )
      puts "Got #{myPage}:  #{resp.message}"
      # do something on a successful HTTP request.
    rescue TimeoutError => tErr
      # do something on an HTTP request that did timeout.
    end
  }
end

threads.each { |aThread|  aThread.join }
```

Comment: I'm not really looking to do this

Comment: Well, your time-consuming operation in the thread is really the HTTP request. So, why not?